# individual colours for grouped boxplots in seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I'd like to adjust the colour scheme to this boxplot so that the group on the left are dark & light blue, and on the right dark and light red. I've made the colours I want in `my_colours` but I still can't figure out how to do it. Here's the code for the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

a1 = list(np.random.normal(.70, .20, 20))
a2 = list(np.random.normal(.5, .15, 20))
b1 = list(np.random.normal(.78, .20, 20))
b2 = list(np.random.normal(.4, .25, 20))



levsA = ['a' for i in range(40)]
levsB = ['b' for i in range(40)]

itemsa = [1 for i in range(20)] + [2 for i in range(20)]
itemsb = [1 for i in range(20)] + [2 for i in range(20)]



df = pd.DataFrame({'cs':a1 + a2 + b1+ b2,
                   'levels':levsA + levsB,
                   'type':itemsa + itemsb})


my_colours = ((0.1216, 0.4667, 0.7059),
              (0.8392, 0.1529, 0.1569),
              (0.6824, 0.7804, 0.9098),
              (1, 0.5961, 0.5882))
sns.set_palette(my_colours)


sns.boxplot(x='type', y='cs', hue='levels', data=df)
```

[image]

I would like them in this order:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boxes are `PathPatch`es. You may loop over them and set their color. One would need to pay attention to the order they appear in the axes though.

```
import matplotlib.patches
boxes = ax.findobj(matplotlib.patches.PathPatch)
for color, box in zip(my_colours[::2]+my_colours[1::2], boxes):
    box.set_facecolor(color)
```

[image]